# Create table with attribute which must be in range of 1-10 (Postgres)

Tags: sql, postgresql

How can i constrain an attribute in a table to only allow the value to be between 1-10?
This is the statement so far.. Have no idea how to make the OfficeNumber only accept values in that interval

```
CREATE TABLE OfficeStaff(
    EID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    OfficeNumber INT NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use a `check` constraint:

```
CREATE TABLE OfficeStaff (
    EID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    OfficeNumber INT NOT NULL,
    CHECK (OfficeNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10)
);
```

Note, though, that there is another, perhaps better approach.  You should have an `OfficeNumbers` table with the valid office numbers.  Then you can use a foreign key relationship to enforce the numbering, without having to hard-code the numbers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use domains for this purpose:

```
create domain mydomain as integer check(value between 1 and 10)

create table mytable(id serial primary key, md mydomain not null)
```

-- this two will succeed

```
insert into mytable(md) values(1)
insert into mytable(md) values(2)
```

-- that one will fail

```
insert into mytable(md) values(12)
```

ERROR:  value for domain mydomain violates check constraint "mydomain_check"

********** Error **********

ERROR: value for domain mydomain violates check constraint "mydomain_check"

More information can be found here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createdomain.html

Comment: Thx, check is gonna be enough for this, but this could sure be useful for me in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add [constraints](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/ddl-constraints.html) for the definition. In this case you can add

```
CHECK (OfficeNumber BETWEEN 1 AND 10)
```